# cannot convert string into float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
    Sales       Discount    Profit      Product ID
0   0.050090    0.000000    0.262335    FUR-ADV-10000002
1   0.110793    0.000000    0.260662    FUR-ADV-10000108
2   0.309561    0.864121    0.241432    FUR-ADV-10000183
3   0.039217    0.591474    0.260687    FUR-ADV-10000188
4   0.070205    0.000000    0.263628    FUR-ADV-10000190
5   0.697873    0.000000    0.281162    FUR-ADV-10000571
6   0.064918    0.000000    0.261285    FUR-ADV-10000600
7   0.091950    0.000000    0.262946    FUR-ADV-10000847
8   0.056013    0.318384    0.257952    FUR-ADV-10001283
9   0.304472    0.318384    0.265739    FUR-ADV-10001440
10  0.046234    0.318384    0.261058    FUR-ADV-10001659
```

Am using K elbow method to find the right number of cluster

## **Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters**

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def kelbow(final_df,k):
        from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
        x = []
        for i in range(1,k):
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i)
            kmeans.fit(final_df)
            x.append(kmeans.inertia_)

        plt.plot(range(1,k), 30)
        plt.title('The elbow method')
        plt.xlabel('The number of clusters')
        plt.ylabel('WCSS')
        plt.show()
        return x
```

Returning the function,
kelbow(final_df,30),

But the code is throwing the error as,
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'TEC-STA-10004927'
How can i find the clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Make dummy variables.

```
final_df = pd.get_dummies(final_df, columns=['ProductID'], dtype=('int64'))
final_df = final_df.drop(['ProductID'], axis=1)
```

Comment: if i run that above code, this is the error,
None of [Index(['Product ID'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def kelbow(df, k):
  x = []
  final_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns)

  for i in range(1,k):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i)
    kmeans.fit(final_df)
    x.append(kmeans.inertia_)

  plt.plot(range(1,k), 30)
  plt.title('The elbow method')
  plt.xlabel('The number of clusters')
  plt.ylabel('WCSS')
  plt.show()

  return x
```